# Laravel 5 How to dynamically include External CSS and JS file depends on controllers/routes

Tags: laravel-5

I'm wondering what could be a good way to 
dynamically include a js file in my main blade
template like this

```
<?php
$currentRoute = Route::currentRouteName();
$currentRoute = $currentRoute?$currentRoute:'home';
$currentRoute = explode('.',$currentRoute);
  ?>
<script src="{{$currentRoute[0]}}.js"></script>
```

but just a less tricky :)

Answer (score 5):

I did something like that in that past.
Here, is my "trick" to do this.

First you need a top level controller class

```
class MainController extends Controller {

   protected static $js_files  = [];
   protected static $css_files = [];

   public static function boot()
   {
      view()->share('js_files', static::$js_files);
      view()->share('css_files', static::$css_files);
      parent::boot();
   }
}
```

Then, all of your controllers must inherit from your MainController class.

The reason I use the keyword "static::" instead of "self::" is because I want to retrieve the latest child properties and not the "MainController" property, which would gave me the keywords "self::".

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php
In your blade layout, in the head section do the following :

```
@foreach($css_files as $src)
   <link href="{{$src}}" rel="stylesheet">
@endforeach
```

and before your closing body tag

```
@foreach($js_files as $src)
    <script src="{{$src}}"></script>
@endforeach
```

In each controllers, you have to put in the $js_files and $css_files inherited properties the sources of all of your js/css.

if you want to include a JS/CSS only for one route, you can add the source of the file directly in the method.

And voilà !

Comment: after extending MainController where to bind js and css in controller? Suppose i have create method then into that mehod? Also how to pass this variable into blade template?

Comment: You can do it wherever you want to. Constructor or any method you want.